# symfony read distant files and auto clear cache when files are updated

Tags: php, symfony

I have a website on symfony, and I need to use [translations files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html), not from a Bundle or from the server itself, but from a NAS on the same NFS. How can I directly read these translations files? I was thinking about [translation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html) and did something like this:

```
$translator->addResource('yaml', 'path/to/messages.fr.yml', 'fr_FR');
```

or in my case :

```
$translator->addResource('xliff', 'path/to/messages.fr.xlf', 'fr_FR');
```

*(cause i need to use xliff files, but it's not really important...)*

---

But it's not my only problem... 
If I update a translation files on my NAS, 
*(I suppose it can be read by my server as I say before or by whatever solution you want...)* 
this file will be not read by my server because it is already in the cache *(yes, my server will be in prod mod, so I need to consider the cache)*

So I need in a second time to delete the cache of my translation folder *(/cache/translation)* but only if there is updated translation files on my NAS. And I don't want to do that from FTP/SSH or whatever, I need the server which delete good cache files by itself.

**Is it possible?** 
Or have you some ideas?

Comment: hm, I think I would rather handle that via a bash script (run from cron) or something to copy the translation files and delete the cache folder. that way youre not putting the overhead on the webserver every time someone loads your script.

Comment: You could try using the Lexik Translation Bundle ( https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle ) and loading your updated translation in to the database rather than needing to clear your cache each time.